# Plotting results from Findroot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I know this has been asked, but I cannot seem to understand the solutions. What I need to know, because I have my first domiciliary test this Monday, is how to plot the output from `FindRoot` for a system of equations as the parameters vary

I havent even been able to do it with one equation either

Say I have define

```
g[x_, y_] := 2 x + y
```

I can define the function

```
t[y_] := FindRoot[g[x, y], {x, 1}]
```

Wich does give me an answer for different y, but when I plot

```
Plot[t[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

It wont do anything. I mean, the axis appear but nothing will be drawn on it.

If I had a system of equations, `FindRoot` would give several values, say `{x, y}`.

How can I draw `x[d]`, `y[d]`, where this last two are the roots of FindRoots for different values of parameter `d`?

Thank you very much and I am very sorry if this is really simple but I havent been able to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: Have you look at the [many other questions about plotting and `FindRoot`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bplotting%5D+findroot+is%3Aq+answers%3A1)?  You may find some help there.

Comment: I did. I try with several, specially making changes to this one, but in the solution i can not understand what [[1,2]] are, but i fI remove then it does not plot and it gives errors 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23573/plot-findroot-for-non-trivial-function

Comment: Many of the answers suggest trying `t[y_?NumericQ] := ...`.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037 for more information. -- oh, and be sure to `ClearAll[t]` before trying the `?NumericQ` fix.  -- and thanks for editing the question.

Comment: Thank you Michael! I did try with that option before, but the solution neither worked for the graphic neither was required for the function to work without actually plotting it

Comment: D'oh -- I meant to include `t[y_?NumericQ] := x /. FindRoot[...]`

Comment: Thank you Michael! That actually worked! The key was ClearAll[t]. I have only used Matlab in the past, which step on every variable created. Seems Mathematica its a bit more sensible!

Answer (score 8):

Thank you Michael!! I will write the answer here for other people.

```
t[y_?NumericQ] := x /. FindRoot[g[x, y], {x, 1}]
```

worked like charm

Comment: `First @ FindRoot` will have your function return a number instead of a list.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple results you could do for example:

```
g1[x_, y_, z_] := 2 x + y - z
g2[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 - y^3 - z^2
t[x_] := t[x] = {y, z} /. FindRoot[{g1[x, y, z], g2[x, y, z]}, {{y, 1}, {z, 1}}]
Plot[{t[x][[1]], t[x][[2]]}, {x, 1, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ContourPlot3D[{g1[x, y, z] == 0, g2[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, -5}, {z, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]